# I turn right - Riddle

Tags: riddle

Solve the following riddle:

> I turn right.
>        Then I leave home.
>        Then I turn left.
>        Then I turn left.
>        Then I turn left.
>
> Who am I?

Comment: Seems too broad to me ... but I'll wait in case a really nice solution comes out :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are a

> Baseball player *batting left-handed* and rounding the bases

The only way that the first line is accurate is if you are

> Left-handed

The rest of the pieces follow as

> The player rounds the bases, turning left each time

The version of this that I originally heard didn't have the first line and had you returning to home as the last line.

Comment: A righty might twist around (while doing the thing he's there to do) far enough that he has to turn back to the right. Of course that could be a problem for lefties then. I agree that it's better without the first line.

Comment: @Geobits I interpreted it as when he "does the thing that he's there to do" is the right turn.  It is an issue for lefties taking the first step, with the crossing and all.

Comment: A righty might turn right when starting at home, depending on which side he came from. I think it's kinda funny that I edited my answer to include your main point just a few minutes before you answered. I probably posted my edit while you were writing this.

Answer (score 14):

I think you are

> A baseball player, rounding the bases.

However, I think there could be a problem with this (either the riddle or my answer). If you are

> Right-handed and on the team in the third base–dugout. Then you could possibly go from the dugout, to the on-deck circle, to the batter's box, and then on your way to first in a mostly straight, sligtly left-turning path. Then you would "leave home" without turning right.

I'm probably overthinking things in that part, though.

Answer (score 3):

My answer would be:

> A Nascar driver, they only go left once they left home and enter the circuit.

Since:

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

You are a

> key
> You turn right, unlocking the door, then you leave home (the key had been turned only once becuase someone was home).Then you leave home and, from outside, you turn "to the left" three times, to lock the door

Comment: Why does it turn left three times? Is the person OCD?

Comment: @KSmarts I really don't get what you mean. The number of times a key has to be turned depends on the door.