# Who are these guys?

Tags: riddle

I was at my home.

Suddenly, I started running. After a distance, I turned left. Later, I took a left turn again.

After covering some distance, I took another left and reached my home.

When I reached home, I saw two guys wearing masks.

Who are these guys?

Comment: Very similar to: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/9537/i-turn-right-riddle

Comment: With one less turn, this could be a version of the north pole puzzle, and the guys would be arctic explorers.

Comment: I have a quibble with the term *my home*, in normal baseball terminology home plate is often referred to as "home" never as "my home".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These two guys are

> the catcher and referee at a baseball match.

I was at my home.

> Home base, before batting.

Suddenly, I started running.

> You run after hitting the ball.

After a distance, I turned left. Later, I again took a left turn.
After covering some distance, I took another left and reached my home.

> You run to first base, then second, then third, and then back to home base.

When I reached home, I saw two guys wearing masks.

> The catcher and referee there both wear protection masks.

Comment: I expect this is the right answer, but in that case the question is actively misleading because it says "I do not know who are these guys", and in that situation you absolutely would know who they are.

Comment: I have edited my question as I see this can be misleading. Although good and quick response. Great.